# Add something so the user can browse and select specific video file from the hard disk

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button5.Enabled = false;
    button1.Enabled = false;
    wmv = new Polkan.DataSource.WmvAdapter(@"d:\VIDEO0040.3gp", sf,label2);
    wmv.SaveToDisc = true;
    wmv.Start();
    if (wmv.done == true)
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

In this case I have a static video file but I want that the user will be able to select his own video file.

Types of video files like: mov, 3gp, avi and others.

Comment: you want an [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the proper Filter set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an OpenFileDialog control to allow the user to select the video from the disc. Insert the control into the form, is called OpenFileDialog.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

    }
```

You can also add a filter in case you want to search only for certain type of files

```
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Video Files (.avi)|*.avi|All Files (*.*)|*.*|Music Files (.mp3)|*.mp3";
```

Comment: @jsve: There is a C# (and VB.Net) example in the link I included in a comment to the original question.

Comment: the file variable will contain the file name that the user selected